# Array elements not removing when going too fast on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello guys I have an input box which adds the val text inside it as an anchor tag to the renderAdded div whenever a user clicks the Add word button. Once they are added the user should be able to remove every element when they click them. The thing is that is working BUT if you go too fast on clicking them, the DOM elements will be removed on the frontend BUT not all of them from the array.

You can see that in the `console.log("after removing: ", arr)`.

Any suggestions?

```js
var keywords = []

$("button").click(function(e) {
  var key = $('#' + "inputText").val();
  keywords.push(key)
  addOnDiv(keywords)
  removeKeywordOnClick(keywords, "renderAdded")
});


function addOnDiv(arr) {
  var formatedKeywords = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
    var k = '<a  class="ui label deleteKeyword">' + arr[i] + " ; " + '<i  data-value="' + i + '" class="delete icon"></i></a>';
    formatedKeywords = formatedKeywords + k;
  }
  $("#renderAdded").html(formatedKeywords);
}

function removeKeywordOnClick(arr, idDiv) {
  $("#" + idDiv + " > a").click((evt) => {
    var index = $(evt.target).children().attr("data-value")
    $(evt.target).remove()
    arr.splice(index, 1);
    console.log("after removing: ", arr)
    $('#' + "inputText").val("")
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="renderAdded"></div>
<input placeholder="Type something" id="inputText" type="text">
<button>
Add word
</button>
```

Comment: using [`.on` and event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) would simplify this code a lot.

Comment: I can't re-create your issue. *BUT if you go too fast on clicking them* this doesn't happen in the code you've added. My guess you have something else getting in the way here. Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem

Comment: Liam is happening just try to insert hello and click the Add word button multiple times so more hellos will appear above. Then click every single one of them fast so they will be removed in the DOM. However, you will see in the output below that the after removing array won't be empty although they wont appear in the HMTL...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically what's happening is that you have multiple sources of truth which are falling out of synch.

The 'keywords' array is used to set up the displayed list of words when adding a word, but when removing a word you delete the clicked DOM element directly and then only indirectly update 'keywords' after the fact via passing a reference to it (as `arr`) between your functions.   (You'll note that if you delete a bunch of words quickly and then add one, the "extra" words that are still lingering in `keywords` will re-insert themselves into the DOM.)

Here I've simplified that to a single source of truth:  everything runs based directly on the `keywords` array, no array reference is passed between the functions, and the clicked elements aren't deleted directly (instead `addOnDiv()` is called a second time to redraw the whole list based on the `keywords` array.

```js
var keywords = []

$("button").click(function(e) {
  var key = $('#' + "inputText").val();
  keywords.push(key)
  addOnDiv()
  removeKeywordOnClick("renderAdded")
});


function addOnDiv() {
  var formatedKeywords = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < keywords.length; ++i) {
    var k = '<a  class="ui label deleteKeyword">' + keywords[i] + " ; " + '<i  data-value="' + i + '" class="delete icon"></i></a>';
    formatedKeywords = formatedKeywords + k;
  }
  $("#renderAdded").html(formatedKeywords);
}

function removeKeywordOnClick(idDiv) {
  $("#" + idDiv + " > a").click((evt) => {
    var index = $(evt.target).children().attr("data-value")
    //$(evt.target).remove()
    keywords.splice(index, 1);
    addOnDiv();
    removeKeywordOnClick("renderAdded")
    
    console.log("after removing: ", keywords)
    $('#' + "inputText").val("")
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="renderAdded"></div>
<input placeholder="Type something" id="inputText" type="text">
<button>
Add word
</button>
```

You could simplify this further by putting the "delete" event on the container and delegating it to the `<a>` tags; this way you don't have to bind new event handlers every time you add a word. (I also moved the data attribute to the `<a>` itself, somewhat more convenient than traversing to the child `<i>` to find it.)  This makes your functions a lot more DRY: 'add' and 'remove' both change the keywords array and then call the same function to redraw the list into the DOM.

```js
var keywords = []

$("button").on("click",function() {
  keywords.push($('#inputText').val()) // add the word
  drawKeywords()
});

$('#renderAdded').on("click","a",function() {
  keywords.splice($(this).data("value"),1) // remove the word
  $("#inputText").val("") // clear the input field
  drawKeywords()
});

function drawKeywords() {
  var formattedKeywords=''
  for (var i=0; i<keywords.length;i++) {
    formattedKeywords += '<a data-value="' + i + '" class="ui label deleteKeyword">' + keywords[i] + " ; " + '<i class="delete icon"></i></a>'
  }
  $("#renderAdded").html(formattedKeywords)

  console.log(keywords)
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="renderAdded"></div>
<input placeholder="Type something" id="inputText" type="text">
<button> Add word</button>
```